# Making a questionnaire that depends on user's previous answers

Tags: python, python-3.x, survey

I've recently started coding a Python program in which I want to 'guide' the user throughout the answers. I think the best way to put it is by giving an example:

So let's say I have a questionnaire in which I have 2 questions, but those can only be asked if the user replies to a previous question:

- Q1: Are you 18 or over?
- A1: yes (*redirects to question two*)
- A1: no (*redirects to text saying the user can't take part in questionnaire)

I'm also trying to do some more things with it. My full plan is:

Have an initial question that asks which one of the three functions the user wants to use.

- First function: check if the user is avaible for applying (age, status etc.)
- Second function: list the step-by-step to applying
- Third function: provide a list of Q&As.

The code I have written until now is only for the first function and has many mistakes (I've never coded before).

- How do you format this coding in a way that it'll fit the whole scheme of what I want to do?
- How do I make it so that whenever the user makes a mistake (not typing y or n) it doesn't crash and instead loops back to the question?

My code so far:

```
print ("Answer all yes or no questions with Y or N")
while True:
  idade = input("Are you over 18? Y/N")
  if idade.lower() not in ('y', 'n'):
    print("Answer only with Y or N")
  else:
    if idade == "Y" or idade == "y":
      crime = input("Have you ever been arrested or convicted before?")
    if idade == "N" or idade == "n":
      print("Sorry, you can't apply. ")
  if crime.lower() not in ('y', 'n'):
      print("Answer only with Y or N")
  else:
     if crime == "Y" or crime == "y":
      print("Sorry, you can't apply. ") 
     if crime == "N" or crime == "n":
      visto = input("Do you have visa TYPE_A'? ")
  if visto.lower() not in ('y', 'n'):
    print("Answer only with Y or N")
  else:
        if visto == "Y" or visto == "y":
          print("THAT'S AS FAR AS I'VE GONE")
        if visto == "N" or visto == "n":
          print("THAT'S AS FAR AS I'VE GONE")
          break
```

Comment: You could make use of [PyInquirer which supports conditional question with property `when`](https://github.com/CITGuru/PyInquirer#question-properties).

Answer (score 1):

```
def valid_input(message):
  inp = input(message)
  while inp.lower() not in ('y','n'):
    inp = input('Please input "y" or "n" only. ' + message)
  return inp.lower() == 'y' # So the return value is simply True or False


print ("Answer all yes or no questions with Y or N.")
while True:
  idade = valid_input("Are you over 18? Y/N: ")
  if not idade:
    print('Sorry, you can\'t apply.')
    break
  crime = valid_input("Have you ever been arrested or convicted before? Y/N: ")
  if crime:
      print("Sorry, you can't apply. ") 
      break
  else:
    visto = valid_input("Do you have visa TYPE_A'? ")
    if visto:
      print("THAT'S AS FAR AS I'VE GONE")
      break
    else:
      print('You don\'t have that visa type.')
      break
```

To "remember" previous values, simply reuse the variable name.
Example:

```
question = valid_input('Question: ')
another_question = valid_input('Another: ')
if question:
    # Do stuff
    if another_question:
        # Do other stuff
```

Comment: This makes it much more organized, but would I be able to go back to the questions further on the questionnaire? Such as, let`s say - I would be able to know (within the program) that the person has answered y in question one when I ask her question 6 or something.

Comment: I guess I could go back to something like input in visto/crime etc.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might be quite over-kill, but I think it's a nice use of dictionaries to create a system of inter-linked questions. The bonus of this solution is that if you need to repeat a question or suchlike, you don't have to type out the same thing twice. It also is easily expandable, and looks quite clean.

The dictionary `questions` uses names of questions as its keys.  The first question is always `"START"`, but you can change this if you want. Each question is its own dictionary, allowing you to have text printed, a prompt, potential actions, and also decide what happens when a certain answer is chosen.

- The key `"text"` is used if you want to tell the user something which isn't a question, and is executed first. You can use `"text"` and `"prompt"`, although this is probably not necessary.
- `"prompt"` is simply what the question is.
- `"y"` and `"n"` are the names of the question that you want to go to if that answer is picked.
- `"action"` is used to tell the program if there's something that needs to be done when the question is asked. The only action I've implemented is to end the questionnaire.

To run the program, call `exec_questions(questions)`, where `questions` is your dictionary.

```
questions = {
    'START':
        {
            'prompt':'Are you 18 or over?',
            'y':'q2',
            'n':'fail'
        },
    'q2':
        {
            'prompt':'Have you ever been arrested or convicted?',
            'y':'fail',
            'n':'q3'
        },
    'q3':
        {
            'prompt':'Do you have a visa TYPE_A?',
            'y':'q4',
            'n':'fail'
        },
    'q4':
        {
            'text':'THAT\'S AS FAR AS I\'VE GONE',
            'action':'end'
        },
    'fail':
        {
            'text':'Sorry, you can\'t apply',
            'action':'end'
        }
}

def exec_questions(questions):
    print("Please answer all questions using y/n")

    this_question = questions['START']
    while True:
        if 'text' in this_question.keys():
            print(this_question['text'])

        if 'action' in this_question.keys():
            if this_question['action'] == 'end':
                return

        if 'prompt' in this_question.keys():
            while True:
                res = input(this_question['prompt']+"\n > ").lower()
                if not res.lower() in ('y','n'):
                    print("Please type y/n")
                    continue
                break

            this_question = questions[this_question[res]]

exec_questions(questions)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I think this will work quite well. If I bump into any other problems, I'll make sure to post them here.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd set up a function.

```
def q(question):
    answer = input(question).lower()
    if 'y' is answer:
        return True
    elif 'n' is answer:
        return False
    else
        print('invalid input')
        return q(question)
```

This function can be called by your code at any point and will return either true or false. If the user inputs 'y' then true, and false if 'n' is input. If neither are input then the function is called again. The function can then be called like so:

```
if q('Are you 18? (N/Y)'):
    if q("Have you ever been arrested or convicted before?"):
        #and so on
if q()#input question in here if the user isn't over 18
```

You can then 'nest' your questions like above.

Comment: This type of nesting the questions will be quite useful, thanks for your help.